# Reading objects from JSON file iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I read a JSON file in this way:

```
NSString *fileContentHomework = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:homeworkPath];

SBJsonParser *parserHomework = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSDictionary *dataHomework = (NSDictionary *) [parserHomework objectWithString:fileContentHomework error:nil];

NSArray *nameofHomework = [dataHomework objectForKey:@"nameH"];
NSArray *homeworkDifficulty = [dataHomework objectForKey:@"difficultyH"];

CHOrderedDictionary* DictionaryHomework = [CHOrderedDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:homeworkDifficulty forKeys:nameofHomework];
```

...then...

```
NSArray *allKeys2 = [DictionaryHomework allKeys];


        for (int i = 0; i < [allKeys count]; i++) {
```

....

```
NSString *key2 = [allKeys2 objectAtIndex:i];

            NSObject *obj2 = [DictionaryHomework objectForKey:key2];

            int val;
            val = [key2 intValue];
```

....

The JSON file looks like this:

```
{"difficultyH":["name", "name"],"nameH":["2", "2"]}
```

I noticed that if the data in the file is equal, like above, the app gives me an objectAtIndex error, while if the data is different, like in the following case, the app works fine:

```
{"difficultyH":["name", "name2"],"nameH":["2", "3"]}
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with JSON.  In the first case you're trying to construct an NSDictionary with duplicate keys.  That won't work.